# ¿Cómo deshabilitar días en el datepicker de android?

Tags: android, datepicker

Tengo este `fragment`:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private TextView lblFechaHacerReserva;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        lblFechaHacerReserva = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.LblFechaHacerReserva);
        lblFechaHacerReserva.setText(String.valueOf(year)  +  "-" + String.valueOf(month+1) + "-" + String.valueOf(day));
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo deshabilitar apareciendo los días en gris o similar, los días anterior a la fecha actual y los días a partir de la fecha que yo le diga?

Answer (score 4):

Si usas un **[DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html)**, lo correcto es usar el método **[setMaxDate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate(long))** el cual como puedes ver en la documentación esta disponible desde la api 11 de Android.

```
myDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se debe usar `setMaxDate()` ya que es el método usado para configurar el `DatePicker`, ya que `setMinDate()` según la documentación es usado para el `NumberPicker`, ver definiciones en la documentación:

> **setMaxDate()** (agregado en API 11) Establece la fecha máxima soportada
>   por el DatePicker en milisegundos desde el 1 de enero 1970 00:00:00
>   en getDefault() zona horaria.
>
> **setMinDate()** (agregado en API 11) Establece la fecha mínima soportada 
>   con este NumberPicker en milisegundos desde 1 de enero 1970 00:00:00
>   en setDefault () zona horaria.

Comment: Vale el setMinDate me funciona, pero el setMaxDate, es decir, a partir de la hora que lo quiero desactivar no me funciona; he hecho esto:  DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(getContext());
        datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        datePicker.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() * (1000 * 172800));  debería desactivarse pasado dos día y no funciona. Ideas?

Comment: Estaba usando y devolviendo otro objeto. Un fallo tonto. setMaxDate funciona perfectamente, por ejemplo se puede hacer: Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  calendar.set(year, month, day+3) y despues datepickerdialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMilis()); Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Hola @Red acabo de ver tus comentario, de hecho se puede usar setMaxDate() ya que setMinDate es para ser usado con el NumberPicker!!! =0 he editado mi respuesta! =)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar esto, pero creo que no es compatible con versiones inferiores a 5.0
En la documentacion del DatePicker no aparece nada sobre ocultar campos y lo que aparece por la web es respecto al DatePickerDialog, pero supongo que la base sea la misma.

```
Private DatePickerDialog createDialogWithoutDateField() {
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(_activity, ExpiryDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth, cday);

    try {
        Field[] datePickerDialogFields = dpd.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) { 
            if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
                datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);

                DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField.get(dpd);
                Field datePickerFields[] = datePickerDialogField.getType().getDeclaredFields();

                for (Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                    if ("mDayPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                        datePickerField.setAccessible(true);

                        Object dayPicker = new Object();
                        dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                        ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception ex) {
    }

    return dpd;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673842/android-hide-date-field-in-datepickerdialog

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401915/hide-year-field-in-android-datepicker

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056643/hide-date-from-date-picker

Suerte!