# Como restringir valores minimos y maximos de un DatePickerDialog que emerge de un EditText de tipo Date en Android?

Tags: android, datepicker

Quiero establecer el valor mínimo y máximo de un `DatePickerDialog` que emerge al darle clic a un `EditText` de tipo Date, según lo que he investigado se puede realizar con esto:

```
setMaxDate(long maxDate)
setMinDate(long minDate)
```

Pero no se como aplicarlo al código que tengo, mi código es el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static EditText fechauso, horainicio;
    private int anio, dia, mes, hora, minuto;
    private static final int TIPO_DIALOGO = 0;
    private static DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener oyenteSelectorFecha;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fechauso = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_fechadeuso);
        horainicio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_horainicio);

        horainicio.setOnClickListener(this);
        fechauso.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        anio = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        oyenteSelectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                anio = year;
                mes = monthOfYear;
                dia = dayOfMonth;
                mostrarFecha();
                horainicio.requestFocus();
            }
        };

        fechauso.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    closeSoftKeyBoard();
                    mostrarCalendario(fechauso);
                }
            }
        });

        horainicio.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    closeSoftKeyBoard();
                    mostrarTime();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void mostrarCalendario(View control) {
        showDialog(TIPO_DIALOGO);
    }

    public void mostrarFecha() {
        fechauso.setText(anio + "-" + (mes + 1) + "-" + dia);
    }

    public void mostrarTime() {
        // Get Current Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        minuto = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {
                horainicio.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute + ":00");
            }
        }, hora, minuto, false);

        timePickerDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, oyenteSelectorFecha, anio, mes, dia);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void closeSoftKeyBoard() {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == horainicio) {
            closeSoftKeyBoard();
            mostrarTime();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar **[setMinDate(long maxDate)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate(long))**

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

y  **[setMaxDate(long minDate)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long))**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2016, 6, 18);
datePicker.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

actualización:

Recordaba que existía una pregunta similar aquí **[¿Cómo deshabilitar días en el datepicker de android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/10057/95)**, este sería un ejemplo:

Definimos variables para configurar nuestro DatePickerDialog:

```
   private int miAnio, miMes, miDia;
```

Este es un ejemplo para crear un DatePicker y definir una fecha minima, por ejemplo definimos que sea el mes anterior y un día antes:

```
  Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
    miAnio = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    miMes = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    miDia = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog oyenteSelectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(year) + String.valueOf(monthOfYear) + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth));

        }
    }, miAnio, miMes, miDia);


    //Como ejemplo: deseamos que la fecha minima sea un mes antes y un dia antes.
    Calendar calendarioMin = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarioMin.add(Calendar.MONTH, - 1); //Mes anterior
    calendarioMin.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, - 1); //dia anterior
    //defines que el día que deseas
    oyenteSelectorFecha.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendarioMin.getTimeInMillis() - 1000);
    oyenteSelectorFecha.show();
```

Por lo tanto tu DatePicker únicamente permitirá como mínimo valor el definido en `calendarioMin.getTimeInMillis()`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Elenasys comprendo que ese es el codigo que necesito aunque lo que me confunde es en que parte adaptarselo al mio

Comment: Y ambos ejemplos que pusiste son 2 formas diferentes de hacerlo para setMinDate?

Comment: Perdón el segundo es setMaxDate, en el primer ejemplo para setMinDate() se toma la fecha actual como párametro, en el segundo ejemplo se define una fecha a partir de calendar para setMaxDate()

Comment: ah bien aunque aun te falto modificar lo que va dentro de los parentesis jeje no te preocupes, bueno la duda que tengo es que en mi codigo ya tengo: `Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();` que utilizo para el `oyenteSelectorFecha` lo sustituyo o es aparte?

Comment: Son ejemplos de hecho en la documentación indica lo que debe recibir como párametro tanto setMinDate(long maxDate) como setMaxDate(long minDate) . Exactamente puedes usar "calendario.getTimeInMillis()" pero después de definir sus valores de año, mes y dia!

Comment: DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        anio = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        calendario.set(2016, 6, 18);
        datePicker.setMaxDate(calendario.getTimeInMillis());

Comment: Puede ser únicamente  
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(); y después defines la fecha  calendario.set(2016, 6, 18);

Comment: No comprendo porque pero me aparece Cannot resolve constructor'DatePicker()'

Comment: crees que la forma en la que estoy haciendo para que muestre el DatePickerDialog al hacer clic al EditText es muy confusa?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41112/discussion-between-elenasys-and-guillermo-vargas).

Answer (score 1):

Debes de obtener el `DatePicker` y a él poner los límites.

```
DatePickerDialog dateDialod = new DatePickerDialog(this, oyenteSelectorFecha, anio, mes, dia);
dateDialod.getDatePicker().setMinDate(<aquí van los milisegundos de la fecha>);
```

Comment: Hola amigo, te refieres a poner exactamente la fecha en milisegundos donde pusiste <aqui van los milisegundos de la fecha> o aparte ingresar otro codigo

Comment: Tal cual los milisegundos, por ejemplo:
`dateDialod.getDatePicker().setMinDate(1465794000000)`

O bien

`datePicker.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());`

Comment: Es que con la opcion `dateDialod.getDatePicker().setMinDate(1465794000000)` marca este error: Integer number too large  y con `datePicker.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());` me surge el siguiente error: Cannot resolve method setMaxDate(long)

Comment: Lo siento, agrega una "L" al final para que sea de tipo long, así:

`dateDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(1465794000000L);`

Con `datePicker.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());` no deberías tener problema, ese error aparece porque seguramente tu `datePicker` es el diálogo y no el picker, o estas escribiendo mal el nombre del método, intenta copiar lo siguiente: `dateDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());`